# Jquery append don't function in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, incompatibility

Please, why this code dont function in Firefox?

```
var path = 'http://www.facedabeauty.com.br/teste/0/display/' 
var i = 2; 

$('.gallery a').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.lightbox').removeClass('preloader').fadeIn();
    $('.display').html('<img src="'+path+i+'.jpg" />').addClass('imgdisplay');
```

In Mozilla,is oppened the image in browser, not append the img tag.

You can see an example in: http://codepen.io/Mpleandro/full/CaAip

Answer (score 3):

you call `event.preventDefault()`  and this would create an error, and because of that the rest of the code is not executed. you need to change this:

```
$('.gallery a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
```

jQuery passes its event object as first parameter to the callback function.
the global object `event` does not exist in every browser and should not be used.
Always use the jquery event that is passed as first parameter to your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

change `event.preventDefault()` to `e.preventDefault()`, and add the `e` parameter to your anonymous function callback.

```
var path = 'http://www.facedabeauty.com.br/teste/0/display/' 
var i = 2; 

$('.gallery a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.lightbox').removeClass('preloader').fadeIn();
    $('.display').html('<img src="'+path+i+'.jpg" />').addClass('imgdisplay');
```

Comment: Just one question: What means the 'e' inside function()... What i can do with it or another thing i put there?